# Trying to create a one page login to signup script php

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, passwords

I'm trying to create a really "simple login to signup" page.

I have a wordpress page-template and when someone goes to i.e. /signup they will be greeted with an input asking them to provide a password, if this password is correct the input will change to a form I've created which they can fill in and then send.

The form is already in place and works great. It looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Required field names
$required = array('fullname','email','country','age','gender','os','cpu','ram','gfx','hdd','speed');

// Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
$error = false;
    foreach($required as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    if ($error) {
        echo '<label class="error">There was an error with your application. <br />Please make sure you have filled in everything marked with an asterisk.</label>';
    } else {
        $username="user";
        $password="root";
        $database="database";
        $host="localhost";

        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
        mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die("Unable to select database");

        $fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['fullname']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
        $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['country']);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['age']);
        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['gender']);
        $beta = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['beta']);
        $press = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['press']);
        $os = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['os']);
        $cpu = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cpu']);
        $ram = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['ram']);
        $gfx = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['gfx']);
        $hdd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['hdd']);
        $speed = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['speed']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) ) {
            print '<label class="error">That Email address is already registered acording to our records</label>';
        }
        else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO enroll_beta VALUES ('','$fullname','$email','$country','$age','$gender','$beta','$press','$os','$cpu','$ram','$gfx','$hdd','$speed')";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

                print '<label class="success">Thank you for your participation, we will be in touch</label>';
        }
    }   
}
```

And the form looks like this:

```
<form class="betaform" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_attr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
```

So what I would like to do now is to WRAP this whole thing in a simple password protection script that basically just checks another table in my database called "password" and if the password exists in the db it will "echo" the form together with the above code.

I've tried with the sessionscript which I found here: [Password protect a page?(with db access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225720/password-protect-a-pagewith-db-access)

It seems good, but I don't think session will work for me since I want to keep all this on one page with no connections.

Any ideas or thoughts? I'm lost and I've been searching like a mad man.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick notice, It's important that it's looking for the passwords in the DB since I will have 100 different passwords. although it's not important that you can use the password more than once, that's a risk I'm willing to take.

Comment: Why session wont work here?

Comment: i think its really suits your needs http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php